# dynamically construct an ordered html table from a json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

An ajax response is returning json object and I want to construct a table from. The json contain the column headers in an array and the actual data in another array of dictionaries. I want the table columns to be ordered according to the array of headers:

```
{
    "columns": ["id", "category"],
    "data":[
      {"category": "fruit","id": 1},
      {"category": "diary","id": 2}
    ]
}



  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(event) {
      $.ajax({
        data: {
          user: $('#user').val(),
        },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/process'
       })
        .done(function(response) {
         if (response.error) {
          alert('Error!');
        }
        else {
          var html = '<table class="table table-bordered"><thead><tr>';
          jQuery.each(response.columns, function(index, value) {
              html += "<th>" + value + "</th>"
          })
          html += "</tr></thead><tbody><tr>"
          jQuery.each(response.data, function(index, value) {
               jQuery.each(response.columns, function(idx, col) {
                    html+="<td>" + value[col] + "</td>"
               })
          })
          html+="</tr></tbody></table>"
          $(resulttable).append(html);
        }
       });
      event.preventDefault();
     });
    });
```

I'm getting a table like this:

```
id   category
1    fruit      2     diary

instead of 

id   category
1    fruit      
2    diary
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new table row for each data row.

```
      html += "</tr></thead><tbody>"
      jQuery.each(response.data, function(index, value) {
           html += "<tr>"; //new code
           jQuery.each(response.columns, function(idx, col) {
                html+="<td>" + value[col] + "</td>"
           })
           html += "</tr>"; //new code
      })
      html += "</tbody></table>"
```